# Symfony2: Roles, Users and Grants from Database

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm beginning to use Symfony2 and I'm really enjoying it!

I have some questions for sure that you will help me easily!

When we use the security layer, the file security.yml we set the property access_control, usually something like this:

- {Path: ^ / admin roles: ROLE_ADMIN}

Traditionally using php, my rule of access to the system I use 3 tables:

- User - Users Table
- Role - Roles Table
- Resource - Resource Table
- Permission - Grant Tables

Where, User has a role, and a permission is related to a role and a resource. To check whether the user has access to a resource, check the table permission.

Bringing Symfony2, the property "path" would be a resource and ROLE_ADMIN would be the role of the user.

How to do that security.yml, load the settings from the database. I searched the official documentation and found nothing.

For now, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the way to "read" the path (in the [security.yml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html) file) is:

```
- { path: ^/this/(path|regex|here)$, roles: {CAN_BE_ACCESED_ONLY, BY_THESE_ROLES} }
```

now, from where do you know which user has which role?

From [wherever you load your users.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded)

e.g.:

```
public function getRoles()
    {
        return array('ROLE_USER');
    }
```

Comment: my need is to create a custom permission/roles and store it into database.
exactly like phpBB do.

Comment: for dinamy routing check [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/bundles/routing/dynamic.html).

For dynamic access control, you can check [voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) and [acl lists](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find your answers here. It descripes how to load users from Database:

[How to Load Security Users from the Database (the Entity Provider)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)

I would recommend to use FOSUserBundle. It is very easy to handle and helps you managing your Security in Symfony2

[FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

Regards!

Comment: My problem is different, FOSUserBundle just solves a part of my problem.